# How will i install react properly in my local

Tags: reactjs

I have install the npm globally using npm install -g create-react-app command. After that i have created react app using npx create-react-app react app command but it got stuck in middle seems like not creating properly.
And at last it shows run npm audit fix and this also I have tried to run but then it throws error. I have also tried to start the npm but it says script missing.please help me so that i can install react on my local.

Comment: maybe its because you cant include a space in the name of your project try this:
npx create-react-app react-app

Comment: Add all the errors here as well, it will help users to get more information and help you out.

Answer (score 0):

First, uninstall create-react-app. Recent changes have made it so that it can't be run if it's globally installed on the local machine.

`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

Next, run it using npx - npx can pull the latest version, and directly pulling it every time is the current preferred configuration.

`npx create-react-app my-react-app`

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you have installed the node js and npm installed already.You can check the same as below using cmd.

```
        -->node -v[should have version greater than 6.0]
        -->npm -v
```

Then execute in cmd for creating React project as below

```
          -->npm init
          -->npm install create-react-app
          -->npx create-react-app <project name>
```

This should work,after creating you can start development server at http://localhost:3000 by default as below

```
              --> cd <your project name>
              --> npm start
```

Comment: i hv follow the same steps as u have mentioned but nothing works...seems like stuck in middle and at last it shows this -------------- found 1 low severity vulnerability                             run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Comment: Did u able to create the project?Or else u have stuck on starting the app?

Comment: project is created and only package.json, lock.json and node modules are visible and rest of the folders are missing

Comment: unable to get the last happy hacking msg